# vue.js <img src>

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Изучаю компоненты vue.js (вместе с Laravel) и наткнулся на проблему: не отрисовывается картинка. Вставляю путь `<img src="/path/to/img">` и в браузере в debug выдаёт 404 не находит картинку... Без компонента всё ок,
в чём может быть проблема?

Код компонента:

```
<template>
    <div class="card main-card">
        <div class="card-header main-card-header">Ваш Аккаунт</div>

        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="purses">
                    <div class="row">
                            <img src="/public/img/1.jpg">
                        <div>
                            Тест
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {

  }
</script>

<style>
  /*тут много стилей*/
</style>
```

Comment: :src="'/path/to/img'"

Comment: Пробовал, такая же проблема. Но если вставлять с любого хостинга, то всё ок

Comment: Насколько помню, Laravel по умолчанию смотрит в public.
Т.е. в вашем случае <img src="/img/1.jpg">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый правильный способ использовать картинки - это подключить в проект file-loader https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader (тут подробное описание), тогда ты сможешь не хардкодить путь к картинке (который может поменять со временем), а просто импортить ее

```
<template>
  <img :src="image"
</template>
<script>

import image from 'relative/path/to/image'; //file-loader вернет путь к картинке
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      image
    };
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
:src="'/path/to/img'"
```

Либо вынесите в переменную:

```
<template>
    <img :src="image"
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            image: '/path/to/img'
        };
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Пробовал, не получается... Проблема в том что если указывать путь с любого хостинга то ок, но если подгружать локально, то не работает... Указываю путь из папки public: /public/img/имяФайла

Comment: Так какое это отношение имеет ко `Vue`?

Comment: Если не использовать компонент, то картинки отрисовывается без ошибок

Comment: Покажите код компонента

Comment: Добавил в шапку

Comment: + еще объясните, что значит если не использовать компонент, то картинка грузится, картинка то у Вас в компоненте?

Comment: На одном из форумов пишут что webpack'ер при сборке заменяет выражения, но как мне ему конкретнее показать где картинка?

Comment: webpack к этому не имеет отношения, это эмулятор commonjs / es6 окружения в браузере

Comment: Если просто вставить в чистую html разметку ту же картинку по тому же пути (laravel blade) всё ок, но компонент отказывается то же самое делать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80676/discussion-between-overthesanity-and-).

Answer (score 2):

Нужно использовать require. Например:

img :src="require(`../assets/${item.img}`)"

Объяснение, почему это нужно по адресу:
https://webformyself.com/zagruzka-izobrazhenij-vo-vue-i-nuxt/